# Almacenar múltiples valores en local storage

Tags: javascript

Aqui tengo mi script que trae todos los datos necesarios.

```
function guadar_localStorage(){
    var id = parseInt(document.getElementById("cedula").value);
    var clave=document.getElementById("key").value;
    var ident=localStorage.getItem("Cedula");
    var contra=localStorage.getItem("Password");
        if(id==ident && clave==contra){
            location.href="inicio.html";
        }else{
            var answer=prompt("Su Id y pass no se encuentran registrado desea guardarlos (S/N)");
                if(answer=='s' || answer=='S'){
                    localStorage.setItem("Cedula",id);
                    localStorage.setItem("Password",clave);
                    document.getElementById("cedula").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("key").value = "";
                }
        }
}
```

quiero saber que cantidad de informacion puede almacenarse en el localstorage porque cuando ingreso un nuevo usuario se borra el que ya estaba guardado o si lo estoy haciendo mal como seria, por favor ayuda y muchas gracias.

Comment: Es un error garrafal guardar la contraseña en local storage, y peor aún sin usar un algoritmo de cifrado. Yo te recomendaría que utilizaras un back-end para gestionarlo y crear tokens de acceso. Si es un proyecto escolar, esta bien para que aprendas como se usa, pero en operaciones estarías fuera. La cantidad que quieras guardar el local es infinita, por su puesto se recomienda utilizar la menor cantidad de datos para que el navegador no se coma la memoria.

Comment: Alberto Siurob  solo estoy practicando js , no estoy haciendo desarrollo profesional ademas aun nose conectar una base de datos con js por eso pedi informacion sore eso . pero igual gracias por tu repuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Buenas!

El problema del codigo que nos muestras esta en las siguientes lineas (lineas 11 y 12 de tu codigo):

```js
localStorage.setItem("Cedula",id);
localStorage.setItem("Password",clave);
```

Ahí estas sobreescribiendo cualquier valor que hubiera antes.
En LocalStorage los datos tienen un formato clave:valor, por tanto le estas diciendo que guarde en la clave **Cedula** el valor del id, sobreescribiendo lo que hubiera.

Yo te voy a proponer una solución. Ya que la contraseña si puede repetirse, pero el ID no deberia repetirse, puedes poner el ID como clave y la contraseña como valor. Te dejo el codigo por aqui:

```js
function guadar_localStorage() {
    //Obtenemos los valores del html.
    var id = document.getElementById("cedula").value;
    var clave = document.getElementById("key").value;

    //Si el id existe en el localStorage vamos a comprobar la clave
    if (id in localStorage) {
        //Si la clave coincide le permitimos el acceso.
        if (clave == localStorage.getItem(id)) {
            location.href="inicio.html";
        }
        //Si la clave no concuerda, le informamos de que no es correcta.
        else {
            alert("Su contraseña es incorrecta.");
        }
    }
    else { 
        //Si el id no se encuentra, le preguntamos si quiere agregarlo.
        var answer = prompt("Su Id y pass no se encuentran registrado desea guardarlos (S/N)");
            if (answer == 's' || answer == 'S') {
                localStorage.setItem(id,clave);
                document.getElementById("cedula").value = "";
                document.getElementById("key").value = "";
            }
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver en el codigo ahora la clave que se almacena en localStorage es el propio id del usuario, y su valor es la contraseña. para acceder a la clave usamos el id que nos proporciona el mismo usuario.

Ademas encadenar un condicional dentro de otro nos permite no sobreescribir un valor si el usuario se equivoca al meter su clave.

En el primer condicional, para saber si existe usamos el `if (id in localStorage) {...}` ya que no necesitamos almacenarla para nada. Si necesitaramos almacenarla quizas necesitariamos recorrer todas las keys con un bucle y el metodo `localStorage.key(indice)` hasta dar con la correcta.

Espero que el codigo te sea instructivo y puedas entiender mejor como puedes manejar distintas claves y valores con localStorage.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: muchisimas gracias RuDaHee me has salvado de esa gran duda que tenia , muchisimas gracias.